# How to change this Hibernate property to not require a SQL statement

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate dynamic-map to load DataEntry objects in my application. When I load any given DataEntry object, I want to retrieve the descriptive value of its InformationTypeId column. The DataEntry table's InformationTypeId is actually a code into the InformationType table. What I want Hibernate to do in the mapping file is to look-up the InformationType row for the DataEntry object and return the value of its InformationDesc column.

Here are the tables and columns:

```
create table DataEntry (DataEntryID, InformationTypeId)
create table InformationType (InformationTypeId, InformationTypeDesc)
```

The following hbm.xml file does what I would like for loading. In the informationType property, I specified the column using the read attribute. This invokes that specific SQL query.

```
<class entity-name="DataEntry" table="DataEntry">
    <id name="dataEntryId" type="string">
        <column name="DataEntryID" length="36" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="informationType" type="string">
        <column name="InformationTypeId"
                read="(SELECT TOP 1 InformationType.InformationDesc FROM InformationType WHERE InformationType.InformationTypeId = InformationTypeId)"/>
    </property>
</class>
```

The approach above does work for loading. It has two problems though:

1. Updates don't work
2. It requires manual SQL (MS SQL Server).

Is there a way I can customize this behavior without the SQL statement?

This seems like something that would be fairly common, but I've not seen any examples of it. I have tried the following using a join, but it does not work. I believe that this join does not work because the join is trying to join using DataEntry's private key. I need it to join using DataEntry's InformationTypeId.

```
<join table="informationType" optional="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="InformationTypeId"/>
    <property name="informationType" type="string">
        <column name="InformationDesc"/>
    </property>
</join>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map the `InformationType` table to an `InformationType` entity, and have an eagerly fetched many-to-one association between `DataEntry` and `InformationType`.

Comment: Will this produce an object for InformationType instead of a just string for InformationDesc?

Comment: Yes, but that's what you have in database: a data entry references a row in InformationType, having an ID and a description. And I guess the same information type ID can be referenced by many DataEntries, so you need a way to get an existing information type and attach it to a DataEntry.